# How to allow IAM user to administer a AWS resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I am trying to allow one of my IAM users on AWS to administer Amazon Cognito. That means set it up get it up and running for testing etc. What policy should I add to that user to be able to do this? I added the premade policy of `AmazonCognitoPowerUser` would that be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

The AmazonCognitoPowerUser policy states as below.

"Provides administrative access to existing Amazon Cognito resources. You will need AWS account admin privileges to create new Cognito resources."

You can always simulate the privileges using https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?# before enabling the policy.

-/Ak